# Whats wrong with my setDataSource?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

This makes no sense, i have seen many others use this setDataSource method for media players but now android studio tells me my code will only be good with android Nougat. what am i doing wrong?

```
tmp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        tmp.setDataSource(fd);//<<<<<ERROR HERE it says "call requires API level 24, min 16
    }catch(IOException e){}
    tmp.setSurface(surface);
    tmp.prepareAsync();
    tmp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            tmp.start();
        }
```

Comment: fd is the name i gave to my FileDescriptor

Comment: Are you sure it isn't actually an **Asset**FileDescriptor?

Comment: I'm trying to set a video to my textureview so i can do some animations with it like fade in and out transitions. In the effort to replace my videoview i needed a different way to set the video file to my media players. I dont know if thats the right way or if there is another way. 
EDIT: It is an asset file descriptor! Should i be using javas file descriptor instead?

Comment: I think you should read the API for the correct method, or show us a [mcve]. We cannot see what `fd` is, so it's hard to answer your question. AssetFileDescriptor does require API 24 or higher, though. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor)

Comment: cricket_007 is right: `setDataSource(AssetFileDescriptor afd)` was added in 24 so your `fd` is `AssetFileDescriptor`, not `FileDescriptor`

Comment: You were right i am using AssetFileDescriptor because i was getting an error while using the normal FileDescriptor. 
`fd=getAssets().openFd("vbg.mp4");`
It says- incompatible types
Required- Java.io.FileDescriptor 
Found- Android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor

Comment: see `AssetFileDescriptor#getFileDescriptor`

Comment: I've given up on the filedescriptor and assetfiledescriptors. I just need a way to set the data source to this media player. There must be another way

Comment: just use `getFileDescriptor` and in general read the official documentation more

Comment: Is putting the file in your `raw` folder an option? Then you could just create the Media Player using `mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.your_media_file);`